# PartiQL Query to return items in a list of objects that contains certain string

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, partiql

I want to retrieve only the short_name that contains the string "BR", I've tried using PartiQL docs but some features are not allowed in DynamoDB.
The reason is that right now we are using DynamoDB for Geocache wrong and now I need to filter for a specific country.

```
SELECT googleResult.address_components FROM Geocache
```

This is the current return for this query:

```
"address_components": {
                    "L": [
                        {
                            "M": {
                                "long_name": {
                                    "S": "803"
                                },
                                "short_name": {
                                    "S": "803"
                                },
                                "types": {
                                    "L": [
                                        {
                                            "S": "street_number"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "M": {
                                "long_name": {
                                    "S": "Rua Sócrates"
                                },
                                "short_name": {
                                    "S": "R. Sócrates"
                                },
                                "types": {
                                    "L": [
                                        {
                                            "S": "route"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "M": {
                                "long_name": {
                                    "S": "Jardim Marajoara"
                                },
                                "short_name": {
                                    "S": "Jardim Marajoara"
                                },
                                "types": {
                                    "L": [
                                        {
                                            "S": "political"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "S": "sublocality"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "S": "sublocality_level_1"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "M": {
                                "long_name": {
                                    "S": "São Paulo"
                                },
                                "short_name": {
                                    "S": "São Paulo"
                                },
                                "types": {
                                    "L": [
                                        {
                                            "S": "administrative_area_level_2"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "S": "political"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "M": {
                                "long_name": {
                                    "S": "São Paulo"
                                },
                                "short_name": {
                                    "S": "SP"
                                },
                                "types": {
                                    "L": [
                                        {
                                            "S": "administrative_area_level_1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "S": "political"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "M": {
                                "long_name": {
                                    "S": "Brasil"
                                },
                                "short_name": {
                                    "S": "BR"
                                },
                                "types": {
                                    "L": [
                                        {
                                            "S": "country"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "S": "political"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "M": {
                                "long_name": {
                                    "S": "04671-205"
                                },
                                "short_name": {
                                    "S": "04671-205"
                                },
                                "types": {
                                    "L": [
                                        {
                                            "S": "postal_code"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that in DynamoDB, as you have the data stored in a List and you are not able to search every component in a list for a given value. Why not store the values as a `Map` with the short_name code as its key?

```
"address_components": {
  "M": {
   "803": {
    "M": {
     "long_name": {
      "S": "803"
     },
     "short_name": {
      "S": "803"
     },
     "types": {
      "L": [
       {
        "S": "street_number"
       }
      ]
     }
    }
   },
   "BR": {
    "M": {
     "long_name": {
      "S": "Brasil"
     },
     "short_name": {
      "S": "BR"
     },
     "types": {
      "L": [
       {
        "S": "country"
       },
       {
        "S": "political"
       }
      ]
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Now you can do a `Scan` for all items which have a short_name of `"BR"`:

```
aws dynamodb scan \
--table-name tableName \
--filter-expression 'attribute_exists(#v.#x)' \
--expression-attribute-names '{"#v": "address_components", "#x": "BR"}'
```